# Cmake cross-compiling error "cannot find -ldl"

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to build cpp project w cmake. Host machine is linux but target machine is win. It gives -ldl error. help me out. here is my CMakeList;

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Toolchain-mingw.cmake)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(MyCrossCompileProject)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

set(RESTBED_PATH "/home/fca/free_space/restbed/distribution")
set(LIB_PATH "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")

add_executable(my_executable main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(my_executable 
    ${RESTBED_PATH}/library/librestbed.a    
    pthread
    ${LIB_PATH}/libssl.a
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    dl
)

target_include_directories(my_executable
    PRIVATE ${RESTBED_PATH}/include/
)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
```

my error stated below;

```
.
.
.
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable my_executable.exe
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/build.make:108: my_executable.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You can't reuse libraries compiled for Linux for MinGW. You have to compile them with MinGW. That's the reason CMake doesn't find your libssl.a by default, by manually specifying the path you're just hiding the issue.

Comment: Consider using [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2). Among other things it lets you download prebuilt libssl and librestbed for MinGW, and doesn't require any changes to CMakeLists.txt (should work with the same CMakeLists.txt you use for native linux builds).

Comment: `libdl` isn't a widows library, you need to use kernel32 instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya

Comment: As the library that contains `dlopen` and `dlclose` symbols can be different from `libdl` it is advised for CMake to use `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` in `target_link_libraries` command. See [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DL_LIBS.html). This resolves to empty in case of Windows OS.